# Cannot change the background image while the radio button is hovered

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I wrote a radio list with image animate. When it was hovered and checked, it can change to another image. 
it's works on all of the browsers but on IE its not work when I hover on it. 
I don't know if I wrote some css wrong or miss something about ie issue?
the html is:

```
<ul>
<li>
<input type="radio" id="f-option" name="gender">
<label for="f-option" class="gender female"><img src="images/52x42.png"></label>
<div class="check"></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

and my css is:

```
.user-form ul li label.gender.female {
background-image: url(../images/female.png);
}

.user-form input[type=radio]:checked ~ label.gender.female,
.user-form input[type=radio]:hover ~ label.gender.female {
background-image: url(../images/female-checked.png);
}
```

its works all of the browser but not work on ie
can anybody help me fix it?

The online demo is in this bottom of page: 
http://bestinthink.com/wg/buy-p1.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. I'm accessing the female class directly after the label as .gender and .female were siblings.

```
.user-form ul li label.gender.female {
background-image: url(../images/female.png);
}

.user-form input[type=radio]:checked ~ label .female,
.user-form input[type=radio]:hover ~ label .female {
background-image: url(../images/female-checked.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example works in modern browsers because they treat hovering over your label element as though you are hovering over the radio element itself, even though the radio element is set to `visibility:hidden`. IE doesn't behave that way. You have to explicitly hover over the radio element — which you can't do because you've hidden it — to see your `input[type=radio]:hover` styles.
I suggest changing the background-image on `label:hover` rather than `input[type=radio]:hover`. The below code might work for you.

```
.user-form input[type=radio]:checked ~ label.gender.female,
.user-form label.gender.female:hover {
   background-image: url(../images/female-checked.png);
}
```

Use it and let me know how it goes.☺ 
I'll update if I find a less hacky solution.